# @ManyToOne relation inserts null objects in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm new in Spring Data REST and after creating successfully some entities I'm facing a problem.
I have a table shopping_list that contains some shopping_list_products, shopping_list_product has a relation with shopping_list, all of this within a mysql database.
The problem is that when I try to create a shopping list with some products inside, the list is created but not the products. In the response I can see the products with id "null".

These are the classes (avoiding getters/setters):

ShoppingList:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_list")
public class ShoppingList {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
private Date creationDate;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy="shoppingList")
private List<ShoppingListProduct> shoppingListProducts;
```

ShoppingListProduct:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_list_products")

public class ShoppingListProduct {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private boolean checked;
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "shopping_list_id")
   private ShoppingList shoppingList;
```

And this is what happens when I tried to insert some products with postman:

I insert this:

```
{
"name" : "name",
"creationDate" : "2018-12-12",
"shoppingListProducts" : [
        {
            "name" : "product 1",
            "checked" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "product 2",
            "checked" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

And I get a 201 (created) response with this result:

```
{
"name": "name",
"creationDate": "2018-12-12",
"shoppingListProducts": [
    {
        "name": "product 1",
        "checked": false,
        "resourceId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "product 2",
        "checked": true,
        "resourceId": null
    }
],
"resourceId": 60,
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shoppingLists/60"
    },
    "shoppingList": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shoppingLists/60"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the resourceId created for the products within shoppingList is null, and if I go to the database, no products are created.

I can't find what is the problem, so I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show controller too

Comment: @Frighi Controllers are extensions from CrudRepository and has no custom methods.

Comment: You must to have some controller to expose endpoints

Comment: @Frighi , as I said, they're extensions of CrudRepository, from Spring Data. With this, you extend all CRUD actions and endpoints. Nothing custom was added.

Comment: So I don't know, I've never used that and I cannot find an example of spring app without controller

Comment: how about posting your debugging ? like what the JPA providers log says about SQL invoked ...

Comment: @billyFrost, this is what the debug says, it seems that query products are not invoked.

 - insert into shopping_list (creation_date, name) values (?, ?)

 - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2018-12-12]

 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Shopping list name]

Comment: since you dont have cascade set on the 1-N relation (`shoppingListProducts`), why would they be? We dont see what JPA API calls are made ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to @BillyFrost I added a cascade on @OneToMany and after that I received a 500 error saying that shopping_list_id cannot be null. 
So, I edited the setter of shoppingListProducts setting the current shopping list, like this:

```
public void setShoppingListProducts(List<ShoppingListProduct> shoppingListProducts) {

    for (ShoppingListProduct sp : shoppingListProducts) {
            sp.setShoppingList(this);   
    }

        this.shoppingListProducts = shoppingListProducts;
}
```

And now it worked!

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the annotations for id to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean to add it in ShoppingListProduct, changed it and returns absolutely the same. It seems they're added but resourceId is null and it not saved.